# QT Embedded with different font size between Ubuntu PC and STM32MP157C-DK2

Tags: qt

I starting with QT5 Embedded and I made a simple widget example with label but the font size in STM32MP157C-DK2 is biggest than Ubuntu PC. Anyone does have an idea how can I fix this?

Thank you for any help.

QT Creator

[image]

Screen STM32MP157C-DK2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to fix it but I don't know if is the best.

Does anyone know how to config the pixel size on Qt?

Thank you for any help!

Follow the solution I used:

```
#define ADJUST_PIXEL_SIZE_FOR_STM32MP1 1.4

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFont font;

    font = ui->label->font();
    font.setPixelSize(font.pointSize() * ADJUST_PIXEL_SIZE_FOR_STM32MP1);
    ui->label->setFont(font);

    font = ui->label_2->font();
    font.setPixelSize(font.pointSize() * ADJUST_PIXEL_SIZE_FOR_STM32MP1);
    ui->label_2->setFont(font);

    font = ui->pushButton->font();
    font.setPixelSize(font.pointSize() * ADJUST_PIXEL_SIZE_FOR_STM32MP1);
    ui->pushButton->setFont(font);
}
```

[Qt Creator Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XgxD.png)

[Screen STM32MP157C-DK2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2geP2.jpg)